# Flask-SQLAlchemy many to many join condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables, Events, Invites, and Proposals.  I would like to be able to query for events.invites  and return a query of all invitees (and be able to get user's info from my user table, like events.invitees.all()[0].user_name) for that event.  Likewise for proposals.  Reading through the Flask-SQLAlchemy docs I saw how to make many-to-many tables.  I've been trying to get them configured properly but am not having any luck.  This is part of a Flask-App based off Overholt.  Here are my tables:

```
events_invitees = db.Table(
    'events_invitees',
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('events.id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    )

events_proposals = db.Table(
    'events_proposals',
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('events.id')),
    db.Column('proposal_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('proposals.id'))
    )


class EventJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer):
    pass


class Event(EventJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    event_name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    event_mesg = db.Column(db.Text)
    start_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    end_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    event_status = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    rsvp = db.Column(db.Date)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=get_current_time)

    invitees = db.relationship('Invite',
                secondary=events_invitees,
                backref=db.backref('events', lazy='dynamic'))

    events_proposals = db.relationship('Event',
                        secondary=events_proposals,
                        backref=db.backref('events', lazy='dynamic'))


class InviteJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer):
    pass


class Invite(InviteJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'invites'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.Date, default=get_current_time)
    event_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('events.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('users.id'))


class ProposalJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer):
    pass


class Proposal(ProposalJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'proposals'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.Date, default=get_current_time)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    event_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('events.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

This is the error i'm getting: 
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Event.invitees - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'events_invitees'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

Remove this line `event_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('events.id'))` and try like this on `Invite` table

```
class Invite(InviteJsonSerializer, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'invites'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.Date, default=get_current_time)
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

As of [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) we need not specify forignkey on child table because of using 'secondary' argument in parent class.

And also make a change on events_invitees "users.id" to "invites.id" like this

```
events_invitees = db.Table(
    'events_invitees',
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('events.id')),
    db.Column('invite_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('invites.id'))
)
```

Comment: @van This doesn't give me the join error which is great, but I'm a little confused how I can add to my invite table now since I need to hold event_id + user_id to make sense of what an invite is.

Comment: @Ptrkcon: *Part1:* well, you should be asking @Syed, who answered your question. Basically it works because you had two *typos* in your model: 1) redundant `event_id` column on `Invite` and `Proposal` tables; 2) typo in the `event_invitees`: should have been `invite_id` instead of `user_id`. I assume those are left-overs from older non many-to-many model.

Comment: @Ptrkcon: *Part2:* I see your "invite" logic like this: someone (user) invited to some event (event) someone else (user_id) in the invite. It looks to me that the model supports it. Else, please provide more details on what the model is and what you are trying to achieve, so that we do not speak apples/oranges.

Comment: @Ptrkcon: Please better describe your model, especially the cardinality of the relationships.

Comment: @van thanks for the replies.  Syed, sorry I forgot you :)  so I made these changes but what I'm not understanding is how I'd do something like events.get(1).invitees[0].user_name (or any other user attributes).

Comment: You are right. You can access those attributes like you mentioned.